# How to write contactname and contactno row-wise in .csv file in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to take contactname and corresponding contact no from mobile and want to write it in `.csv` file. Each row will contains contact name and contact number of each person for the entire contact list. How to write contact information in `.csv` file?

I write the code for showing contactname column but it display only one contact means its override with existing one so what should be the trick for changing the row for new contact name.

My code

```
       public class contactlist extends Activity {
   static  String name;
   static int count;
   static int countno;
   static File file = null ;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button filterbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    filterbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {


        Uri u1  =   Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Person Details");
         sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
         sendIntent.setType("text/html");
         startActivity(sendIntent);


       }
   });

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

             name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));





          String columnString =   "\"PersonName\",\"phoneno\"";
         String dataString = null;
```

---

I use only name and "phoneno" is hardcoded. But in .csv file only one contact is shown

```
            dataString   =   "\"" + name +"\",\"" + "phoneno" + "\"";    


         String combinedString = columnString + "\n" + dataString;

         File root   = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         if (root.canWrite()){
             File dir    =   new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/PersonData");
              dir.mkdirs();
               file   =   new File(dir, "Data.csv");
              FileOutputStream out   =   null;
             try {
                 out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 try {
                     out.write(combinedString.getBytes());
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 try {
                     out.close();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }



        }



}
    cur.close();
}
```

Comment: Where is code to get contact name and number and create csv.?

Comment: hi pankaj i edited my above code..actually i dont have much idea about how to do it..i am fetching now only contact name for testing ..means show contact name below "ContactName" column ..i hardcoded "phoneno" field so pls can u tell me how to do it..if u have any other concepts your most welcome thanks...

Comment: i am using  String combinedString = columnString + "\n" + dataString;  for add rows below column string but it always replace existing row below column name so how to add row one after other..thanks sir if you can provide me any code for that i will be great thankfull of you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited***.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Pankaj
 *
 */
public class CsvSender extends Activity {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private boolean csv_status = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        createCSV();
        exportCSV();

    }

    private void createCSV() {
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String displayName;
        String number;
        long _id;
        String columns[] = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
        writer.writeColumnNames(); // Write column header
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                   columns,                
                   null,               
                   null,               
                   ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
       if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
           do {
               _id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));   
               displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).trim();
               number = getPrimaryNumber(_id);
               writer.writeNext((displayName + "/" + number).split("/"));
           } while(cursor.moveToNext());   
           csv_status = true;
       } else {
           csv_status = false;
       }
       try {
            if(writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.w("Test", e.toString());
        }

   }// Method  close.  


   private void exportCSV() {
       if(csv_status == true) {
           //CSV file is created so we need to Export that ...
            final File CSVFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv");
            //Log.i("SEND EMAIL TESTING", "Email sending");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/csv");
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test contacts ");           
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n\nAdroid developer\n Pankaj");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + CSVFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); // Shows all application that supports SEND activity 
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email client : " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information not available to create CSV.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   }
       /**
        * Get primary Number of requested  id.
        * 
        * @return string value of primary number.
        */
       private String getPrimaryNumber(long _id) {
           String primaryNumber = null;
           try {
               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                       new String[]{Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE},
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ _id, // We need to add more selection for phone type
                       null,
                       null);
               if(cursor != null) {
                   while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                       switch(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE))){
                           case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           case Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           case Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                               break;
                           case Phone.TYPE_OTHER :
                       }
                       if(primaryNumber != null)
                           break;
                   }
               }       
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.i("test", "Exception " + e.toString());
           } finally {
               if(cursor != null) {
                   cursor.deactivate();
                   cursor.close();             
               }
           }
           return primaryNumber;
       }
}
```

And here is CSVWriter class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

/**
 * @author Pankaj
 *
 */
public class CSVWriter {

    private PrintWriter pw;
    private char separator;
    private char quotechar;
    private char escapechar;
    private String lineEnd;

    /** The character used for escaping quotes. */
    public static final char DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '"';

    /** The default separator to use if none is supplied to the constructor. */
    public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

    /**
     * The default quote character to use if none is supplied to the
     * constructor.
     */
    public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';

    /** The quote constant to use when you wish to suppress all quoting. */
    public static final char NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** The escape constant to use when you wish to suppress all escaping. */
    public static final char NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

    /** Default line terminator uses platform encoding. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_LINE_END = "\n";

    /** Default column name. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME = "Contact Name,Phone Number,";

    /**
     * Constructs CSVWriter using a comma for the separator.
     *
     * @param writer
     *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
     */
    public CSVWriter(Writer writer) {
        this(writer, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_LINE_END);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char, escape char and line ending.
     *
     * @param writer
     *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
     * @param separator
     *            the delimiter to use for separating entries
     * @param quotechar
     *            the character to use for quoted elements
     * @param escapechar
     *            the character to use for escaping quotechars or escapechars
     * @param lineEnd
     *                    the line feed terminator to use
     */
    public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char escapechar, String lineEnd) {
        this.pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
        this.separator = separator;
        this.quotechar = quotechar;
        this.escapechar = escapechar;
        this.lineEnd = lineEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Writes the next line to the file.
     *
     * @param nextLine
     *            a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate
     *            entry.
     */
    public void writeNext(String[] nextLine) {

        if (nextLine == null)
                return;

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {

            if (i != 0) {
                sb.append(separator);
            }

            String nextElement = nextLine[i];
            if (nextElement == null)
                continue;
            if (quotechar !=  NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                sb.append(quotechar);
            for (int j = 0; j < nextElement.length(); j++) {
                char nextChar = nextElement.charAt(j);
                if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == quotechar) {
                        sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                } else if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == escapechar) {
                        sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
                } else {
                    sb.append(nextChar);
                }
            }
            if (quotechar != NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                sb.append(quotechar);
        }

        sb.append(lineEnd);
        pw.write(sb.toString());

    }

    public void writeColumnNames() {
        writeNext(DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME.split(","));
    }

    /**
     * Flush underlying stream to writer.
     *
     * @throws IOException if bad things happen
     */
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        pw.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Close the underlying stream writer flushing any buffered content.
     *
     * @throws IOException if bad things happen
     *
     */
    public void close() throws IOException {
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

And add permissions to manifest as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: vv thanks for responce.its force close on writer.writeColumnNames();in csvsender.java and error is 07-29 12:34:41.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:34:41.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at contactlist.pkg.contactlist.createCSV(contactlist.java:47)
07-29 12:34:41.760: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at contactlist.pkg.contactlist.onCreate(contactlist.java:30)

Comment: My code is running. Say me what is 47th line in your contactlist.java class.

Comment: 47th line is  writer.writeColumnNames(); in your CsvSender class in side of createCSV()  method name

Comment: pls take a look at this linjk i mention all my code and error there http://pastebin.com/uHPpFRYn   i do exact u did but why my code is not running!!!where i am wrong.pls take a look at the link..

Comment: @ram ji Updated answer check it.

Comment: You are running on device or emulator? If device then remove that from USB. And I tried but I couldn't found Null pointer exception. So I can not explain it. Another way put your full code which you are using.

Comment: sir sir :) thanks it works all names coming but in phoneno column null is coming in all  row.means values of phoneno field is null.

Comment: @ram ji Now check your contact details, if there number exists or not. It will work. And upvote my answer also :)

Comment: ya definitely i do.sir but in mobile every field corresponding to name contains also phoneno in my mobile then why itsshowing "null" in place of phone no  column

Comment: Can you tell me in which section your numbers are stored? like Home or Work or Mobile?

Comment: some of store in mobile and some are on home.

Comment: Then it must be work. And if not put case default :
                               primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                             at place of case Phone.TYPE_OTHER