# Send all contacts to mail as CSV file using Android code

Tags: java, android, csv

Hello Every one here the below code is for sending all contacts to mail in `CSV` file format

This is my CSV sender class

```
    public class CsvSender extends Activity {
    private Cursor cursor;
    private boolean csv_status = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_csv_sender);
        createCSV();
        if(csv_status)
        exportCSV();

    }

    private void createCSV() {
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        String displayName;
        String number;

        long _id;
        String columns[] = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };

        writer.writeColumnNames(); // Write column header
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                columns,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME +" COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC" );
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                _id = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).trim();
                number = getPrimaryNumber(_id);
                writer.writeNext((displayName + "/" + number).split("/"));
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
            csv_status = true;
        } else {
            csv_status = false;
        }
        try {
            if(writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("Test", e.toString());
        }

    }// Method  close.


    private void exportCSV() {
        if(csv_status == true) {
            //CSV file is created so we need to Export that ...
            final File CSVFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/my_test_contact.csv");
            //Log.i("SEND EMAIL TESTING", "Email sending");
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setType("text/csv");
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test contacts ");
            emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\n\nAdroid developer\n Sathish");
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + CSVFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); // Shows all application that supports SEND activity
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email client : " + ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information not available to create CSV.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get primary Number of requested  id.
     *
     * @return string value of primary number.
     */
    private String getPrimaryNumber(long _id) {
        String primaryNumber = null;

        try {
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ _id, // We need to add more selection for phone type
                    null,
                    null);
            if(cursor != null) {
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    switch(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE))){
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                            primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                            primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                            primaryNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            break;
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_OTHER :
                    }
                    if(primaryNumber != null)
                        break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("test", "Exception " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if(cursor != null) {
                cursor.deactivate();
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return primaryNumber;
    }
    }
```

This is my CSV writer class

```
/**
 * Created by ADMIN on 23-01-2018.
*/

class CSVWriter {
private PrintWriter pw;
private char separator;
private char quotechar;
private char escapechar;
private String lineEnd;

/** The character used for escaping quotes. */
public static final char DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '"';

/** The default separator to use if none is supplied to the constructor. */
public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';

/**
 * The default quote character to use if none is supplied to the
 * constructor.
 */
public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';

/** The quote constant to use when you wish to suppress all quoting. */
public static final char NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

/** The escape constant to use when you wish to suppress all escaping. */
public static final char NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER = '\u0000';

/** Default line terminator uses platform encoding. */
public static final String DEFAULT_LINE_END = "\n";

/** Default column name. */
public static final String DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME = "Contact Name,Phone Number,";

/**
 * Constructs CSVWriter using a comma for the separator.
 *
 * @param writer
 *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer) {
    this(writer, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
            DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, DEFAULT_LINE_END);
}

/**
 * Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char, escape char and line ending.
 *
 * @param writer
 *            the writer to an underlying CSV source.
 * @param separator
 *            the delimiter to use for separating entries
 * @param quotechar
 *            the character to use for quoted elements
 * @param escapechar
 *            the character to use for escaping quotechars or escapechars
 * @param lineEnd
 *                    the line feed terminator to use
 */
public CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char escapechar, String lineEnd) {
    this.pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    this.separator = separator;
    this.quotechar = quotechar;
    this.escapechar = escapechar;
    this.lineEnd = lineEnd;
}

/**
 * Writes the next line to the file.
 *
 * @param nextLine
 *            a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate
 *            entry.
 */
public void writeNext(String[] nextLine) {

    if (nextLine == null)
        return;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {

        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(separator);
        }

        String nextElement = nextLine[i];
        if (nextElement == null)
            continue;
        if (quotechar !=  NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            sb.append(quotechar);
        for (int j = 0; j < nextElement.length(); j++) {
            char nextChar = nextElement.charAt(j);
            if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == quotechar) {
                sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
            } else if (escapechar != NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER && nextChar == escapechar) {
                sb.append(escapechar).append(nextChar);
            } else {
                sb.append(nextChar);
            }
        }
        if (quotechar != NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            sb.append(quotechar);
    }

    sb.append(lineEnd);
    pw.write(sb.toString());

}

public void writeColumnNames() {
    writeNext(DEFAULT_COLUMN_NAME.split(","));
}

/**
 * Flush underlying stream to writer.
 *
 * @throws IOException if bad things happen
 */
public void flush() throws IOException {
    pw.flush();
}

/**
 * Close the underlying stream writer flushing any buffered content.
 *
 * @throws IOException if bad things happen
 *
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}

}
```

Here I'm able to send my contacts but the mobile numbers which are starting with `+91 are display like (9.1903E+11). How can I solve this please help anyone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do something about it. It is how excell is showing this type of data by default. you need in excell to set another data format for this cell.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6869555/7334718

Comment: yeah i used that code but i giving like that only